# South Africa overstay-undesirable waiver processing time

Tags: customs-and-immigration, south-africa, overstaying

Has anyone had any experience with the South Africa Home Affairs overstay waiver request process?

What is the turnaround time for the waiver? Will the SA border control at the Johannesburg International Airport notice the overstay undesirable status?

Is the status posted to one's electronic immigration record (as a tourist)?

Has anyone used a passport from another country (e.g., dual citizen) to enter SA without issue under these circumstances?